# Can not run a Laravel 5 App with in a Laravel App - Not Found Http Exception

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, routes

I'm new to Laravel and trying to figure out this situation. I have a Laravel 5 app. And now I have to run same application with some changes into its **Sub Directory**. So what I've done is, I've duplicated the application into `v2` **Sub Directory** as follows:

[image]

**.htacceess** at both roots of `Main Application` and `v2 Application`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /


    # Send requests to public directory...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
 # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleRemoveByTag unoeuro
</IfModule>
```

**.htacceess** at `v2 Application` public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase /v2/

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**And this is the result when I access `v2 Application` via http://localhost:8000/v2:**

[image]

I have tried so many ways but failed. Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: have you tried http://localhost/v2 ?

Comment: @phpdroid, yes! but no luck

Comment: can i ask which situation leads you to use this structure?

Comment: most of the time we make folders in controller like V1 V2 V3 and everything is managed here, and in routing you can copy all routes with V2 and maintain changes in those routes

Comment: @phpdroid actually, we have a lot of changes in the second version of application. But we still wants to use both apps parallel like abc.com and abc.com/v2